# Non resident or resident for an F-1 student in Arizona tax purpose

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, f1-student-visa

I'm an F-1 student who lives in Arizona for more than 9 months in the last year.
According to Arizona's [documentation](https://www.azdor.gov/Portals/0/Procedure/itp92-1.pdf) on this question:

> The term "resident" includes:
> (a) Every individual who is in Arizona for other than a temporary or transitory purpose.
>
> (b) Every individual domiciled in Arizona who is outside Arizona for a temporary or transitory purpose. Any individual who is a resident of Arizona
> continues to be a resident even though temporarily absent from
> Arizona.
>
> (c) Every individual who spends, in the aggregate, more than
> nine months of the taxable year within Arizona is presumed to be a
> resident. The presumption may be overcome by competent evidence that
> the individual is in the state for a temporary or transitory purpose.

Is my F-1 student status a competent evidence that I'm in a temporary purpose to live in Arizona?

Also, although I live in Arizona, does it mean I domicile in Arizona? In my comprehension, my permanent home is in my country China. Does it mean I don't domicile in Arizona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, students, even on a visa, are considered residents by the States. See (c) in the quote:

> (c) Every individual who spends, in the aggregate, more than nine months of the taxable year within Arizona is presumed to be a resident. The presumption may be overcome by competent evidence that the individual is in the state for a temporary or transitory purpose.

You'll be staying in AZ for several years, this is in no way temporary or transitory.

In this context, temporary or transitory means, for example, that someone travels extensively and ended up being in AZ more than 9 months by days count. Truck drivers would be a good example. You're not a truck driver.